# Client interpret data returned from Web Api

Tags: xml, json, http, asp.net-web-api

I currently have web api service that takes a parameter to determine whether I should return xml or json.

I also have a service that specifically doesn't dictate what the data should be returned as (so as a client such as Jquery can stipulate the content return type).

As XML is expensive to return from a bandwidth point of view (will cost me more money from my cloud operator) is it possible to restrict the client to JSON only in any way?

I've done the figures and XML is 9 times as fat as JSON - and 9 times the cost!!

Any other ideas as to how to minimise hosting costs for a public API greatly appreciated!?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could do the following:

```
 return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, returnList, Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
```

Which works, but would cause a parse error if the client set the content type to xml.

Its a solution but is it ideal?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you could leverage the conneg feature (content negociation) of REST based on the header `Accept` to specify the expected format the response content instead of a parameter. If you want a JSON content to be returned back, simply add this in your request:

```
Accept: "application/json"
```

It's really difficult to answer your question ;-). Can you give more hints at this level?

If you have the hand on the Web API, we can consider things like that:

- **Block the content negociation (conneg)**. If the client specifies that it expects an XML content, you can send back the HTTP status code `415` (Unsupported Media Type).
- **Ignore the requested format in the case of XML**. You simply only support the JSON format... You always return this format.

You can also implement optimizations on server side:

- **Content compression before sending back**. It can simply consists in minifying or even zip compressing (but it requires that the client uncompress the content). Minifying is often supported by bean / format converters (for example, Jackson).
- **Server-side caching**. According to what your application does, you could add some cache not to always request your datastore.

Hope it helps,
Thierry

Comment: Some good points. I'll probably just force the return type as json. Its a pilot for a number of users so it hosted on an Azure free site so limited ability to manipulate the iis server unfortunately.. thanks